# Difficulty Parsing JSON

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am attempting to update page content on a mobile version of a desktop site by making an Ajax call back to the desktop version. The mobile version of the site lives on a dedicated subdomain, and page content from the desktop versin of the site is being packaged as JSON. The Ajax call is successful, because I am able to log out the JSON object in the console. However, I am unable to isolate the specific part of the JSON object (labeled "content" within the object). The function I've written will not place anything on the page (although it will place other HTML on the page, ruling out that there is something wrong with the function itself), and attempts to log the "content" portion of the JSON object specifically in the console returns "undefined." The code that I'm using for the entire process is this:

```
   function processJSON(url, id){
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {get_param : 'content'},
            success: function(response){
                $(id).html(response.content);                   
            },//ends success
            dataType: 'json',
        });//ends ajax
    };//ends processJSON
```

The arguments for the function are as follows: "url" is the url of the JSON feed (set equal to a variable, usually), and "id" is the id of the div in which I am attempting to place the HTML of the "content" portion of the JSON object.

The JSON response is as follows:

```
  {"status":"ok","page":{"id":9,"type":"page","slug":"scenes","url":"http:\/\/www.davidcharlesbrown.com\/scenes\/","status":"publish","title":"Scenes","title_plain":"Scenes","content":"<h3>I&#8217;ve always been wrapped up in the magic of the stage.<\/h3>\n<p>When I was a junior in high school, I was cast in a chorus role of my first play. I froze as I was about to make my first entrance in front of an audience of several hundred people. The person behind me pushed me on stage, which was the kindest thing he could have done.<\/p>\n<p>Since then, I&#8217;ve been involved in over 100 productions in semi-professional, educational, community, and faith-based settings. I write, direct, design, and occasionally even act. I&#8217;ve also taught acting methods.<\/p>\n<p>I&#8217;m currently a member of the Autism Theatre Network, through the <a href=\"http:\/\/www.appliedtheatrecenter.org\/autismnetwork.html\" target=\"_blank\">Applied Theatre Center<\/a>. I&#8217;m involved with an agency that uses theatre to teach social pragamatics to children, adolescents, and young adults who are on the Autism spectrum.<\/p>\n<p>It&#8217;s a stage of a different sort.<\/p>\n","excerpt":"<p>I&#8217;ve always been wrapped up in the magic of the stage. When I was a junior in high school, I was cast in a chorus role of my first play. I froze as I was about to make my first entrance in front of an audience of several hundred people. The person behind me pushed [...]<\/p>\n","date":"2013-04-10 14:08:27","modified":"2013-04-16 17:34:18","categories":[],"tags":[],"author":{"id":1,"slug":"truthscribe722gmail-com","name":"David Brown","first_name":"David","last_name":"Brown","nickname":"REDACTED","url":"","description":""},"comments":[],"attachments":[],"comment_count":0,"comment_status":"open","custom_fields":{}}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Lets see the response.

Comment: Can you include the JSON string in your question?

Comment: What does the debugger say `response` is when you set a breakpoint inside `success()`?

Comment: Can  you post the format of the returned response?

Comment: @Musa I've edited the question to include the JSON response.

Comment: @Chilpol I've posted the returned response in the question now.

Comment: @PeteScott See above...the JSON object is now in the question.

Comment: @user2512733 The response needs to be a valid javascript object. I'm not sure what any of that is. As a JSON string, it should look more like this part: {status: "ok", page: Object}. That is, brackets around the whole thing, commas separating properties each other (instead of the newlines)... is this actually what the page itself renders when you visit the url directly?

Comment: @user2512733 How are you generating this information?

Comment: I agree with Pete this does not really look like JSON. Moreover even the 'content' variable seems malformed because of the <href="" inside which breaks the consistency of this long string.

Comment: @PeteScott Apologies...I copied/pasted that out of the browser console. I've edited the question again with what appears in the browser with the URL of the JSON object.

Comment: No worries, @Musa has your correct answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`content` is not at the root of the object , it is in the page property.

```
$(id).html(response.page.content);
```

see

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "page": {
        "id": 9,
        "type": "page",
        "slug": "scenes",
        "url": "http://www.davidcharlesbrown.com/scenes/",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Scenes",
        "title_plain": "Scenes",
        "content": "<h3>I&#8217;ve always been wrapped up in the magic of the stage.</h3>\n<p>When I was a junior in high school, I was cast in a chorus role of my first play. I froze as I was about to make my first entrance in front of an audience of several hundred people. The person behind me pushed me on stage, which was the kindest thing he could have done.</p>\n<p>Since then, I&#8217;ve been involved in over 100 productions in semi-professional, educational, community, and faith-based settings. I write, direct, design, and occasionally even act. I&#8217;ve also taught acting methods.</p>\n<p>I&#8217;m currently a member of the Autism Theatre Network, through the <a href=\"http://www.appliedtheatrecenter.org/autismnetwork.html\" target=\"_blank\">Applied Theatre Center</a>. I&#8217;m involved with an agency that uses theatre to teach social pragamatics to children, adolescents, and young adults who are on the Autism spectrum.</p>\n<p>It&#8217;s a stage of a different sort.</p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>I&#8217;ve always been wrapped up in the magic of the stage. When I was a junior in high school, I was cast in a chorus role of my first play. I froze as I was about to make my first entrance in front of an audience of several hundred people. The person behind me pushed [...]</p>\n",
        "date": "2013-04-10 14:08:27",
        "modified": "2013-04-16 17:34:18",
        "categories": [],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "truthscribe722gmail-com",
            "name": "David Brown",
            "first_name": "David",
            "last_name": "Brown",
            "nickname": "REDACTED",
            "url": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "custom_fields": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to note as well. json is easier to read in Musa's format. please try to post it like that next time.